# Implement the Torian

Tags: code-golf, math, factorial

The [Torian](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Torian), \$x!x\$, of a non-negative integer \$x\$ can be recursively defined as

$$
x!0 = x \\
x!n = \prod^x_{i=1} i!(n-1) = 1!(n-1) \times 2!(n-1) \times \cdots \times x!(n-1)
$$

The Torian is then equal to \$x!x\$ for a given \$x\$. This sequence begins \$0, 1, 2, 24, 331776, ...\$ for \$x = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...\$

Alternatively, you can consider the binary function \$!\$ to be instead \$f(x, y)\$. We then have \$f(x, 0) = x\$ and \$f(x, y) = f(1, y-1) \times f(2, y-1) \times \cdots \times f(x, y-1)\$. You should then calculate \$f(x, x)\$.

You are to take a non-negative integer \$x\$ and output \$x!x\$. You may take input and output in any [convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), and you don't have to worry about outputs exceeding your language's integer limit. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

#### Test cases

```
x x!x
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  24
4  331776
5  2524286414780230533120
6  18356962141505758798331790171539976807981714702571497465907439808868887035904000000
7  5101262518548258728945891181868950955955001607224762539748030927274644810006571505387259191811206793959788670295182572066866010362135771367947051132012526915711202702574141007954099155897521232723988907041528666295915651551212054155426312621842773666145180823822511666294137239768053841920000000000000000000000000000
```

And [here](https://tio.run/##XY1BCsIwFETXySlm10QjGN0JuUk3gab6QX5K@EJ6@piKRXA3MPPeLKs8Ml9bm9IMyYUim@rA9qYVzWCEgHPPqiR5FUbVSrLEJwK8VnMuIBCjRL4n4x3q0W/od3QIu5O68@St3j2fXut/wWWDl0Is5geSdUg89cth5JEH29ob) is a reference program that produces output for \$0!0\$ to \$11!11\$

Comment: Brownie points for beating my 10 byte Jelly answer, which may or may not have caused a great deal of discussion around recursion in Jelly in TNB :)

Comment: Out of curiosity does it have any applications?  The wiki page didn't mention any...

Comment: @Jonah Given that the only reference I can find to it is that wiki for large numbers, I doubt it tbh. It isn't even on OEIS, so it's either incredibly obscure, or has no practical applications (or both)

Comment: OEIS(without 0 index): [A068493](http://oeis.org/A068943)

Comment: @Shaggy Uh... If you don't know it, forget it (though there's a challenge on it) Also forget `!` and let's call it `f(x,y)`. The definition of Torian says, the value of `f(x,y)` can be calculated by recursively calculating `f(1,y-1), f(2,y-1), ..., f(x,y-1)` and taking their product. `f(x,0)` is the base case, and is defined to be simply `x`. Then the task is to compute `f(x,x)` for given x.

Comment: In case anyone wants it, the exact formula is \$x!x = \prod_{i=1}^x j^{\binom{2x-i-1}{x-1}}\$ (binomial coefficients in the exponents), except when $x=0$.

Comment: @GregMartin what is j in that formula?

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
R×\⁸¡Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//UsOXXOKBuMKh4bmq/8W7w4figqz//zU)

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes

```apl
{⊃⌽×\⍣⍵⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRV/Ojnr2Hp8c86l38qHfro97NQLL2f9qjtgmPevuAsofWGz9qm/iob2pwkDOQDPHwDP6fdmgFUKEpV5qCAQA)

The main trick is to observe how the computation of `x!y` progresses as `y` increases.

```
1!0=1    2!0=2        3!0=3            4!0=4                ...
1!1=1    2!1=1*2      3!1=1*2*3        4!1=1*2*3*4          ...
1!2=1!1  2!2=1!1*2!1  3!2=1!1*2!1*3!1  4!2=1!1*2!1*3!1*4!1  ...
1!3=1!2  2!3=1!2*2!2  3!3=1!2*2!2*3!2  4!3=1!2*2!2*3!2*4!2  ...
...
```

Basically going to the next row is just a matter of product scan on the previous row. Therefore, to get the value of `x!x`, we can just run product scan on the range `1..x` `x` times, and extract the last element.

One caveat of this approach is that the 0 case must be checked separately. In Jelly, popping from an empty array gives 0. In APL, `⊃` of the empty vector is 0 (`⊢/` does not work in place of `⊃⌽`).

I have 16-byte J and 14-byte ngn/k answers using the same algorithm. Can you find them? (ngn/k code includes converting 0N to 0)

Comment: ngn/k {0^*|x*\/1+!x} is 14

Comment: J: `{:@(*/\@[&1)1+i.` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/q60cNLT0Yxyi1Qw1DbUz9f5rcqUmZ@QrpClpA1UZKhgpGCuY/AcA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @rak1507 I had `{*|0,x*\/1+!x}`

Comment: You can submit the APL answer separately and just say it uses the same algorithm as this one. That def deserves to be its own rep factory!

Comment: @Razetime What's the `0,` for? (I stumbled upon a similar solution (and with ngn's help, almost the same as yours), but I didn't see an edge case that needed `0,`)

Comment: `{*|0,x*\/1+!x}@0` returns `0N` which is not `0`

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
R¡FP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o0EK3gP///5sCAA)

```
       (Starting from [n],)
R      Recursively replace each x with [1..x]
 ¡     n times
  F    Flatten
   P   Product
```

For example `R¡` for the input `4` yields

```
[
    [[[1]]],
    [[[1]], [[1], [1, 2]]],
    [[[1]], [[1], [1, 2]], [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]],
    [[[1]], [[1], [1, 2]], [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]]
]
```

and the product of all numbers in that nested list is 331776.

Comment: That `¡` operator is just not fair!

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
f x=x!x
x!0=x
x!n=product$map(!(n-1))[1..x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwrZCsYKrQtHAFkTm2RYU5aeUJpeo5CYWaChq5OkaampGG@rpVcT@z03MzFOwVSgoLQkuKfLJU9BTKM7IL1dQUYjWyNTJVMzUVKhRyFSw0VUAqTePjf0PAA)

+8 bytes due to the problem needing a function that only takes a single argument. Thanks to @Lynn for pointing that out

Thanks to OVS for pointing out map is shorter than a list comprehension and taking 1 byte off.

My first time ever submitting a haskell answer. I am a beginner so do point out places where I can shorten my code :)

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 39 bytes

```hs
f x=x!x
x!0=x
0!_=1
x!n=x!(n-1)*(x-1)!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwrZCsYKrQtHAtoLLQDHe1hDIzgOKaeTpGmpqaVQAScW8/7mJmXkKtgoFpSXBJUU@eQp6CsUZ@eUKKgrRGpk6aQqZmgo1CpkKNroK0YZ6euaxsf8B)

Thanks to @Alwin for suggesting this version.

Comment: `map` is a byte shorter than a list comprehension: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0LRwLaCq0Ixz7agKD@lNLlEJTexQENRI0/XUFMz2lBPryL2f25iZp6CrUJBaUlwSZFPnoKeQnFGfrmCikK0RqZOpmKmpkKNQqaCja4CSL15bOx/AA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an appropriate comment, but I noticed you can reach 31 bytes using the approach I used in my python answer
x!0=x
0!x=1
x!n=x!(n-1)*(x-1)!n

Comment: I believe you need an extra line like `f x=x!x` for this to be a valid answer.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3 48 bytes

```
f=lambda x,y:f(x,y-1)*f(x-1,y)if x*y else(y>0)+x
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##JYnLCsIwEADv@Yo97tZULIKHgv5LpFldaB7EHLJfH1N6mGFgstZvivfe@bm78N4cNKsr4/C80DRiXqySMLRJwe8/D@2C@rpR51RAQCIUFz8eH7QayEViRbE8ECIjIadSoUrw5nxHXg8hUf8D)

## 55 bytes

if a more conventional input is required. I don't know how to initialize the default 2nd argument to equal the first, so I've rewritten everything as t=x-y without much more thought.

```
f=lambda x,t=0:f(x,t+1)*f(x-1,t-1)if(x-t)*x else(x>t)+x
```

Thanks to Arnauld for saving 3 bytes

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) I don't know that taking both `x` & `y` as the initial input would be valid, though, I think you'd need to initialise `y` to `x` within the function, as I've done.

Comment: Unfortunately, Shaggy is correct here in that you should only take one input, and the second should be initialised to the first

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The 57 byte answer will accept 1 argument, using default t=0 to act as though y=x, since I don't know how to set the default y=x. I hope someone teaches me a better way though!

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <sup><s>53 45</s></sup> 41 bytes

```
[ dup [1,b] [ cum-product ] repeat last ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcw7DsIwEIThPqeYA0AkOgQHQDQ0iMpKsThLsOIX63UBlzeWUn7SP/Miq0na4369XU4IpO9RKC5csLJE9lg4spB3P1KXYtmSol1Fnd2Mwp/K0fZVFlb9ZnFRcR6GI1xSagZzzTCH3XOCga1hnyXN1SomCGcmhafS1QJl9He7ju0P)

A port of @Bubbler's [answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231277/97916); take the product scan (cumulative product) of `1..x` `x` times and then return the last element.

Comment: Didn't know there's a word that's literally `swapd times`. Nice find.

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks. I only learned about `repeat` yesterday and didn't expect to put it to use so soon. It's hidden in the wrong vocabulary.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 27 bytes

```
1##&@@#&//@Nest[Range,#,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b731BZWc3BQVlNX9/BL7W4JDooMS89VUdZRzlW7X9AUWZeSbSyrl2aA5BbF5ycmFcHlo820DGP/Q8A)

Port of Lynn's solution.

---

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
Nest[f1##&@@f~Array~#&,D,#]@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y@1uCQ67f2khYbKymoODml1jkVFiZV1ymo6LjrKsQ7Kav8DijLzSqKVde3SHJRj1eqCkxPz6oIS89JTow10zGP/AwA)

Builds \$x!0...x!x\$:

```
                        D           x => x!0
     f1##&@@f~Array~#&             (x => x!n) => (x => x!(n+1))
Nest[                  , ,#]        x => x!#
                            @#      #!#
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes

Expects and returns a BigInt.

```javascript
f=(x,n=x,g=_=>x?f(x--,~-n)*g():1n)=>n?g():x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoMwEADvvmILHrI1Kc21dvUpVawJLbIRLWUhpF9PzWWYwzDv8Tvu0/ZaP4bDc87ZkRLNJNrTgzrpnRJj9M8wnr3Cm2Wkjvuikl3YlADBlVsQuBNYW6xpEGIFMAXewzJfluDVUEdJp4Kjr@NxxTRgW6X8Bw)

This actually simplifies down to ...

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,n=x)=>n?x?f(x,~-n)*f(~-x,n):1n:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCoMwEETvfsUWPGSrKc1Vu/VXFGtKi@yKlrIQ4q/HeBnmMY/5Dv9hG9fP8rMsryklT0ZrJkV6cqedz7Rbxqs3u80DNo4bTV5Wo0Bw5xYUHgTOna2qEEIBMApvMk@3Wd6mL4PGyxnZL0M@xNhjW8R0AA)

... which is essentially the same as [Alwin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231287/58563).

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
f n=product$iterate(>>= \x->[1..x])[n]!!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7agKD@lNLlEJbMktSixJFXDzs5WIaZC1y7aUE@vIlYzOi9WUTHvf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQm5igUKaAkiJaex/AA)

Same idea as my Jelly answer: starting from `[n]`, repeatedly replace each `x` by `1..x`, `n` times, then take the product.

```hs
  [4]
→ [1,2,3,4]
→ [1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4]
→ [1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4]
→ [1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4]
→ product: 331776
```

Answer (score 5):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>13 12</s> 14 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to ngn

Fixed thanks to Razetime

```
{*|0,x*\/1+!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqvGQKdCK0bfUFuxovZ/mrqi@X8A)

```
{*|0,x*\/1+!x}
           !x  Range [0..x-1]
         1+    Increment range
     x  /      Repeat x times:
      *\       Get the cumulative products of the list
               When this is done y times, we get [1!y, 2!y...x!y]
   0,          Prepend a 0 in case x is 0
 *|            Get the last number (x!y) by reversing and getting the head
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

```javascript
x=>(g=p=>x>1n?x--**p*g(p*y++/i++):x)(i=1n,y=x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBDsIgEADAe1@xxwWK2pvRLr6lqUDWkIW0jaExvh3raS7zmt7TOi9cNiv56VugVslhpEKuukEe1Vqti45Y9G7MmY1Rt6qQaZB@p6payAtg8hswEFzkfjjC9e9R4dMBzFnWnPwp5YjcQ0BWqvu2Hw)

Use

$$ f\left(n\right) = \prod_{i=1}^n i^{{2n-i-1}\choose{n-1}} $$

with exception

$$ f\left(0\right) = 0 $$

Comment: [45 because JS allows *comparison* of floats and bigints](https://tio.run/##FcpBDsIgEADAe1@xxwWK2pvRLr6lqUDWECBtY7Yxvh3raS7zmt7TOi9cN5vL07dATchhpEpO3PAQa7WuOmLVuzFnNkbdRCHTkPudRLVQFsDkN2AguOT74QjXv0eFTwcwl7yW5E@pROQeArJS3bf9AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 46 bytes

```r
x=scan();i=1:x;prod(i^choose(2*x-i-1,x-1))*!!x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc3BCsIwEATQe79ii5fdYsRUPcTaL9CjZ6HGFBdKEpKKEfHbozl6eYcZhgnZ@ZmdjRg1e2N7pRRVIxwEjA@rS4VM8IaoB/uXEsPibOIMzzB4bwJcX3DkwNMEp1VOfRkgddzLfep8cDfki747Fw22TRIs5DIJSdTUdcqfasT17xdloS1sCtvCjvIX)

Using formula from [tsh's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231284/55372) (presumably adapted from [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A068943)).

---

Straightforward recursion:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 50 bytes

```r
f=function(x,n=x)"if"(n,prod(sapply(1:x,f,n-1)),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcs9CoAwDEDh3WM4JRDB@jNU6GFEDRQkDVahnr6a5RsevKsmvWOSDHmLekjw3mPlwI9s1qGQhIJt5BaE9Eo75FX1fMEthZikc4hU/gV6bBicMRijMRkz1g8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
[ɾ?(⁽*r)t
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5B%C9%BE%3F%28%E2%81%BD*r%29t&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

-1 thanks to @AUsername

Comment: [9](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5B%C9%BE%3F%28%E2%81%BD*r%29t&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Comment: @AUsername nice didn't know Vyxal has single function reference builtin

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

-3 bytes by MarcMush.

```julia
<(x,n=x)=n>0?prod(1:x.<n-1):x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQq/i5QUV@CbLVWQorDJkiBbv9fO/9Sz6CGYFOwoos27q3XhP4qAvJ7DGq3bU7ZR@Daz3LVwQIzvyAIqK7JNkA)

Or if we are allowed to take the input as it appears in Torian notation itself (essentially twice), then it becomes:

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 24 bytes

```julia
x<n=n>0?prod(1:x.<n-1):x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0//@/wibPNs/OwL6gKD9Fw9CqQs8mT9dQ06rif1p@kUKFraGVuUJBUWZeSU6eRlJmukaFpk2FpkJqXsp/AA)

Comment: you can use `<` in your first answer for [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQq/i5QUV@CbLVWQorDJkiBbv9fO/9Sz6CGYFOwoos27q3XhP4qAvJ7DGq3bU7ZR@Daz3LVwQIzvyAIqK7JNkA "Julia 0.7 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 9 bytes

```
’ß¥ⱮPðṛḷ?
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLigJnDn8Kl4rGuUMOw4bmb4bi3PyIsIjXFu8OH4oKsIiwiIixbXV0=)

-1 byte thanks to caird coinherinaahing

This is a singular dyadic link. The challenge requires taking one input; however, a single dyadic chain within a monadic link will have the argument supplied to both sides so this works just fine.

```
’ß¥ⱮPðṛḷ?    Dyadic Chain
        ?    If
       ḷ     The left argument is truthy
-----ð       Evaluate on the left argument (this is a variadic chain, and its arity changes between runtimes)
   Ɱ         For each in range on the right argument
--¥          Call as dyad:
’            -  Decrement the left argument
 ß           - Recurse (the `¥` is only necessary to make this act as a dyad since it's a variadic actor)
    P        And take the product
      ṛ      Otherwise, just return x
```

Comment: [9 bytes](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLigJnDn8Kl4rGuUMOw4bmb4bi3PyIsIjXFu8OH4oKsIiwiIixbXV0=)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>38</s> 36 bytes

<sup><s>I still don't understand the challenge but</s></sup> Thanks to Bubbler I understand the challenge a bit better and this port of [Alwin's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231287/58974) seems to work - be sure to `+1` them too.

Only handles inputs up to `4` as anything bigger will result in an output exceeding JavaScript's [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

```javascript
f=(x,n=x)=>n?x?f(x,~-n)*f(~-x,n):1:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDkAwEEDRq1h2VIWFTRmu0qZUiMwIIrNy9ery5@Xv/vV3uLbzMcTzklJEJRWhAI40yRRzfYagjOozGcC2VlLkSwk2vQxdr7VAYLr5WOqDVyXaFVg4nU@A9AM)

For just one byte more, though, we can handle larger inputs by using BigInts:

```javascript
f=(x,n=x)=>n?x?f(x,~-n)*f(~-x,n):1n:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDkRAEEbhq1h2aS3DEsVFLFrQMhP5SxCplav39PLly/tNz3TN5/e4HWRZYwxstAArcY9Bh5DqdaA8mNcloKZCozHIaZQ/aLWrarTWKs2CS/a13GUzan3GmbfppsKP8BT/)

Comment: I'm flattered :) (delete this comment if this is the wrong way to use comments)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 51 bytes

```c
f(n){n=g(n,n);}g(x,n){x=n?x?g(x,n-1)*g(x-1,n):1:x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDBboMwDL33KyykSoEGtUC3as1YD9O@Yu2BpgGidaYiTM2G@PUxQylaGymO/fz8Ylv6mZRtmzJ0a4wzhhxd0WTM0lvbGDd20wd@4Hrk@AHh62BtRdNqrOAz0cjcST0BOh1QKVOZ9x3EUC84BBxCDhGHZSNg7kGC31WuMYNcZ7kqYX8szga@TlAgRKG/11UnYsCbj4LKnpSs1OFOM1ySbhSsVo@N6LkyT0qPrJIfqiQydHRna9/CrX16pfvgcPgfR85QmRYlsO4rjQdlqWwhBvcZjP5RRcquTbjzAfBGRMBs1rNduGzh2jiS0mUbfXonbrKGst3Sb1FF6DjwfdmpJErKnOkB/BcgOzVbpKGQg@Hj5CqOzW6QbSZN@yvTY5KZ1j//AQ)

Port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231285/9481) (which may be based on [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231289/58974)) which, in turn, is based on [Alwin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231287/58563).

Comment: Actually, It's [my solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231289/58974) that's the port of Alwin's ;)

Comment: @Shaggy Fixed! :D

Comment: Scratch that, I see now that he beat me to the `n?x?` version over the original `x*n?` version by a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Shaggy How's that, all perfectly obscure now? T_T

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
h x=iterate(scanl1(*))(1:[1..])!!x!!x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc2xDsIgEMbxvU/xkTiAkUYmEyM@gZujYSAVLdrShtJ4g@9eW0e1Ltxwv/9R2u7uqmq4gDQxyoit9fQG3cbm3BdpUduWMx6kEuKk8pxMdh2tTy7a5HhX2BAVX45LWpEcgTKMEWProfxg1ZtxtZ3OGPFWNNw0/4vEfq/5OLLa@gCNc5MBbZ@OKR4CcnRl88ACJ@5XnnmBJzx2ElO@MQZSIrqLiy4Ubja84iuctSV@fmKL1Ntqtrp9V8ML)

[Product scan method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231277/78410) seems to win over other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 50 bytes

```
t=lambda x,z=0:x*(x-z)and t(x-1,z-1)*t(x,z+1)or x
```

Using the trick of using parameter z=x-y from @Alwin's answer. Before that, I had the 59 byte version

```
t=lambda x,y=-1:x*(y:=(y,x)[y<0])and t(x-1,y)*t(x,y-1)or x
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Make sure to check out our [tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) to see if there are any other ways you can golf this.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
≔ＥＮ⊕ιθＦθＵＭθΠ…θ⊕λＩ∧Ｌθ⊟θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw7DsMgEAV7n4JykZwylSuLylIS@QoEiEGC5R8ppyfrVHnlaOYpK4uK0o@x1uoOhLtMsGHq7dHD0xTgM9tQFRMMNqPBcQKZL9MrFgaZM/JFDEGihjyzvUTdVQPxUd4IG9MJ/3vPacu0F4dkydpgpfJm8GiW7ujhbH7SGNdxefsv) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @Bubbler's answer.

```
≔ＥＮ⊕ιθ
```

Start with a range from `1` to `n`.

```
Ｆθ
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
ＵＭθΠ…θ⊕λ
```

... calculate the cumulative products.

```
Ｉ∧Ｌθ⊟θ
```

Output the last one, unless `n=0`, in which case just output `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
FL}˜P
```

Port of [*@Lynn*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231303/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fzaf29JyA//@NAQ) or [verify the first \$[0,7]\$ test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9@bJKfvZLCo7ZJCkr2fi7/3XxqT88J@K/zHwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
F    # Loop the (implicit) input amount of times:
 L   #  Transform each integer `n` into a [1,n] ranged list
     #  (which uses the implicit input in the first iteration)
}˜   # After the loop: flatten the nested lists
  P  # And take the product of all integers
     # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, because [the new version's `˜` doesn't work on a single integer for input \$x=0\$](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fzaf29JyA//8NAA).

Answer (score 1):

## [ayr](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/ayr), 8 bytes (2 methods)

Method 1:

```
:*/,~$:`
```

Method 2 (doesn't work for N=0):

```
]/]*\$:~
```

## Explanation

```
:       Non J-style train
   ~$:  1-range on each scalar val
      ` Commute input (pass to both sides)
*/,     Product of all scalars
```

Dyadic `A u$: B` is call `u` on previous iteration `A` times with starting value `B`

```
       ~    1-range of N
   *\$:     Repeatedly foldl with multiplication
  ]         N times
]/          Rightmost argument
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 12 bytes

```
⬚0⊢⇌⍥\×:+1⇡.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAg4qyaMOKKouKHjOKNpVzDlzorMeKHoS4KCuKItWbih6E2Cg==)

Pretty much a port of Bubbler's [Jelly/APL answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231277/97916).