# Calculate the (n x "super")factorial

Tags: code-golf, factorial

### Introduction

Factorials are one of the most frequently used examples to show how a programming language works.
A factorial, denoted \$n!\$, is \$1⋅2⋅3⋅…⋅(n-2)⋅(n-1)⋅n\$.

There is also the superfactorial (there are other definitions of this, but I chose this one because it looks more like the factorial), denoted \$n$\$, which is equal to \$1!⋅2!⋅3!⋅…⋅(n-2)!⋅(n-1)!⋅n!\$.

From that you can create an infinity of (super)*factorials (means *any number of times `super` followed by one `factorial`*) (supersuperfactorial, supersupersuperfactorial, etc...) which all can be represented as a function \$‼(x,y)\$, which has two parameters, \$x\$ the number to (super)*factorialize, and y, the number of times plus one that you add the prefix *super* before *factorial* (So if \$y=1\$ it would be a factorial (\$x!=\space‼(x,1)\$), with \$y=2\$ a superfactorial, and with \$y=4\$ a supersupersuperfactorial).

\$!!\$ is defined as such:
\$‼(x,0)=x\$ (if \$y\$ is 0, return \$x\$)
\$‼(x,y)\space=\space‼(1,y-1)\space⋅\space‼(2,y-1)\space⋅\space‼(3,y-1)\space⋅…⋅\space‼(x-2,y-1)\space⋅\space‼(x-1,y-1)\$
<sub>The second definition would have looked cleaner with a pi product \$\prod\$, but it does not display properly. (image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVWXc.png))</sub>

In Python, \$!!\$ could be implemented this way:

```python
from functools import reduce
def n_superfactorial(x, supers):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    elif supers == 0:
        return x
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, [n_superfactorial(i, supers-1) for i in range(1, x+1)])
```

### Challenge

Create a function/program that calculates \$!!(x,y)\$.
Your code is *not* required to support floats or negative numbers.
\$x\$ will always be \$≥1\$ and \$y\$ will always be \$≥0\$.
It is not required to compute \$!!\$ via recursion.
Your program may exit with a recursion error given large numbers, but should at least *theoretically* be able to calculate in finite time any (super)*factorial.

### Test cases

```
Format : [x, y] -> result
[1, 1]    -> 1
[2, 2]    -> 2
[3, 3]    -> 24
[3, 7]    -> 384
[4, 4]    -> 331776
[5, 3]    -> 238878720
[2232, 0] -> 2232
[3, 200]  -> 4820814132776970826625886277023487807566608981348378505904128
```

<sub>Note: if your language does not support integer types that are that large, you are not required to support the last test case.</sub>

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I think (unfortunately) this is a dupe of the [Torian](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/231274/78410) challenge, since most of the algorithms there can be trivially ported here, and some even define !!(x,y) as a helper function. Most notably, Lynn's [4-byte Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231303/78410) works without modification here.

Comment: @Bubbler I looked in the list of possible duplicates, but didn't see that (probably because it does not explicily mention the word `factorial`).

Comment: I just looked at the Torian and one of the definitions (the f(x,y) thing) is exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: @Bubbler I'd say this is a superset of the Torian challenge, and that that one is a dupe of this instead.

Comment: @user Maybe, because the Torian is asking for `!!(x,y)` where `x=y` and this asks for any `x` ≥ 1 and any `y` ≥ 0, but I'm not sure you can mark the past as a duplicate of the future.

Comment: @astroide You can do that, but this question would have to be reopened first.

Comment: @user the question is reopen. What do you think of closing the old one

Comment: The core of the challenges - implementing the function - are the same, and essentially all answers to the older one are portable to this. I've re-closed it because I believe this is a duplicate

Comment: FYI to those who suggested closing the older one: It works only if the older one has quality problems (more specifically, it was written before today's quality standard was established). Otherwise, the newer one is always the one to be closed. Generality of a task has never been a judging factor for closure.

Comment: @OP: May I repost this challenge on [Code Golf Codidact](https://codegolf.codidact.com/)?

Comment: @user Yes, as long as you link to this question as the original.

Comment: @astroide Great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

A naïve recursive implementation.

```apl
{×⍺:×/(⍺-1)∇¨⍳⍵⋄⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/rw9Ee9u6wOT9fXANK6hpqPOtoPrXjUu/lR79ZH3S1AsvZ/2qO2CY96@x71TfX0f9TVfGi98aO2iUBecJAzkAzx8Az@b6iQpmDIZQQkjbiMgaQxlzmYNAGSJmARUy4DkKyRsREA)